# Android - stretch image partially

Tags: android, image

Is there any way to stretch image partially in android? Something like this

[image]

Here, image is stretched in the 1/3 middle section, but left and right endings remains "as is".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is built into android, actually.   Turn that image into a 9-patch.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare your image as NinePatch using [Draw 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) and then loadt it with [NinePatch class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html)

Answer (score 0):

That can be done in code too:

```
int w = myImage.getWidth();
int h =  myImage.getHeight();
int thirdWidht = w / 3;

//create a new blank image
Bitmap stretchImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(w + thirdWidth, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );

Canvas c = new Canvas(stretchImage);

//draw left bit
c.drawBitmap(normalImage, new Rect(0,0,thirdWidht,h), new Rect(0,0,thirdWidht,h), true);

//draw stretched middle bit
c.drawBitmap(normalImage, new Rect(thirdWidht,0,thirdWidht * 2, h), new Rect(thirdWidht,0,thirdWidht * 3,h), true);

//draw right bit
c.drawBitmap(normalImage, new Rect(thirdWidht * 2,0,w,h), new Rect(thirdWidht * 3,0,w + thirdWidht,h), true);

myImageView.setImageBitmap(stretchImage);
```