# Android - ImageView scaling

Tags: android, matrix, imageview, scaling

Is it possible to scale ImageView only in particular part? 
I have a ImageView and I would like to scale it, but only the middle part.
Left side and right would stay the same, stretching occur only in the middle.

Just like on the pic bellow:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - stretch image partially](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712892/android-stretch-image-partially)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally did not know that by heart but simple search showed me this result: [Android - stretch image partially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712892/android-stretch-image-partially)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to leverage 9 patch drawables. A 9 patch is just a special version of your image that has a 1px border that defines the stretchable areas. Android directly supports this, and even has a tool to create the 9 patch images. It's pretty simple.

Documentation here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html